# Magento2: Black screen checkout in mobile verison

Tags: magento2, checkout

We have issue during checkout after display order info cart in mobile version.

Below screenshot:
[image]

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

I have changed `<button` to `<a` before:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var $block \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar */
?>
<?php $themeHelper = $this->helper('MGS\Mpanel\Helper\Data'); ?>
<?php $enbCartDropdown = $themeHelper->getStoreConfig('mgstheme/general/cart_dropdown'); ?>

<div data-block="minicart" class="minicart-wrapper<?php if($enbCartDropdown): ?> minicart-wrapper--dropdown<?php endif ?>">
    <a class="action showcart" href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getShoppingCartUrl(); ?>"
       data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
        <span class="counter qty empty"
              data-bind="css: { empty: !!getCartParam('summary_count') == false }, blockLoader: isLoading">
            <span class="counter-number"><!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko --></span>
            <span class="counter-label">
            <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
                <!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko i18n: 'items' --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            </span>
        </span>
    </a>
    <?php if ($block->getIsNeedToDisplaySideBar()): ?>
        <div class="block block-minicart empty"
             data-role="dropdownDialog"
             data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{
                "appendTo":"[data-block=minicart]",
                "triggerTarget":".showcart",
                "timeout": "2000",
                "closeOnMouseLeave": false,
                "closeOnEscape": true,
                "triggerClass":"active",
                "parentClass":"active",
                "buttons":[]}}'>
            <div id="minicart-content-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
                <h3 class="close-minicart">
                    <?php echo __('Mini Cart') ?> 
                    <a id="close-minicart"><i class="close-cart pe-7s-close pa"></i></a>
                </h3>
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            </div>
            <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('minicart.addons'); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif ?>
    <script>
        window.checkout = <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo \Zend_Json::encode($block->getConfig()); ?>;
    </script>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-block='minicart']": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsLayout();?>
        },
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/block-loader": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif'); ?>"
        }
    }
    </script>
</div>
```

It still does not work for me.

In template folder I found only this results:

```
opc-estimated-wrapper
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to find `minicart-wrapper` class in your theme source, you will get one button under that `minicart-wrapper` DIV tag. Again you need to change it from `button` tag to `a href` tag. After all that changes you may need to run `php bin/magento cache:flush` and `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` commands.

Comment: kunj. It still does not work for me. You can try go to checkout page 2 and try display order info card: czasowewyprzedaze.pl

Comment: it is not updated still button is there. you need to change in `estimation.html` file.

Comment: kunj,  is missing href, I have add <a href class="action showcart" href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getShoppingCartUrl(); ?>"
       data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'"> and then deploy and cache clean but still we have issue with black screen in mobile version.

Comment: ok, try to find `opc-estimated-wrapper` class in source.

Comment: Kunj, you can check my update topic. Thank you.

Comment: @Sylvester, please try to find that in `estimation.html` file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82648/discussion-between-kunj-and-sylvester).